# Is there any good idiom for 'real time' or 'live' data?

Tags: icons, metaphor

The [floppy disk is a good idiom for 'save'](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/save-icon-is-the-floppy-disk-icon-dead), is there any good one for ['real time' or 'live'](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38070/is-the-term-real-time-understood-outside-the-tech-community) data?

I haven't found much on the interweb:

- ['fast text'](http://www.realtimetext.org/standard-graphics), this is meant for IM
- A LOT of clocks in different shapes and colors
- some live camera icons, not a good match because out of the context

**UPDATE**: some clarifications are necessary. What I need is an idea for an icon, based on facts, studies, pre-existing art, conventions and best practices. So not from a graphic design point of view.

Comment: Did you read the answer? The floppy disk is not a metaphor but an idiom. Try something with arrows, data going in and out.

Comment: By metaphor do you mean a visual metaphor?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I meant to write idiom but I lacked brain-hand coordination. Fixing the question now, thanks.

Comment: I think this is really just an icon request question. The save icon question worked well because it came at the issue from the other direction - "Is this icon still appropriate". It wasn't asking for alternatives but was about the specific icon itself. Your question is really just requesting a suggestion for an icon. Can you clarify what it is you want an answer to provide you with?

Comment: I don't need an icon but the idea for an icon. An idea that is easily associable with the concept of real time or live data.

Answer (score 0):

Some news sources I've seen use a "Record" icon (a red circle) which usually fades in and out, to signify real-time news coverage